# Outer automorphisms of direct product of residually finite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, outer-automorphisms

Let $A,B$ be finite generated residually finite groups such that $\mathop{Out}(A)$ and $\mathop{Out}(B)$ are residually finite.
Is $\mathop{Out}(A\times B)$ residually finite?

If not, what is the necessary condition that $A,B$ need to satisfy to make this true? It is quite easy to see that if both $A,B$ are conjugacy separable and have Grossman's property A, i.e. every pointwise inner automorphism is inner - for every $\alpha \in \mathop{Aut}(A)$ we have if $\alpha(a) \in a^A$ for all $a \in A$ then $\alpha \in \mathop{Inn}(A)$ and similarly for $B$, then the group $A \times B$ is conjugacy separable and has proper A, hence by Grossman's theorem $\mathop{Out}(A \times B)$ is residually finite. However, these are quite strong requirements.

Comment: Cross-posted from mathSE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974873/outer-automorphisms-of-direct-product-of-finitely-generated-groups